# How to check if data-attribute does not contain a string with :contains in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to apply `:not(:contains())` selector to data-attribute? Here is what I have in HTML:

```
<input id="keyword">
<button id="find1">Find - 1</button>
<button id="find2">Find - 2</button>

<div class="list_item" data-stringtofind="abc def">abc def</div>
<div class="list_item" data-stringtofind="ghi jkl">ghi jkl</div>
<div class="list_item" data-stringtofind="mno prs">mno prs</div>
```

What I'd like to do is to filter it on click based on what is inside of `data-stringtofind` attribute. I'm trying with this code, but it's not working.

```
$('#find1').on('click', function () {

    var findthis = $('#keyword').val();

    console.log(findthis);

    $( ".list_item.data('stringtofind'):not(:contains("+ findthis +"))").hide();
    console.log(".list_item.data('stringtofind')");

});
```

Here is what the console outputs:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .list_item.data('stringtofind'):not(:contains(abc))
```

Am I doing some simple mistake or this just isn't possible to do with :not:contains?

This code works, but it searches inside of the div, not inside of the data-stringtofind attribute.

```
$('#find2').on('click', function () {
    var findthis = $('#keyword').val();

    console.log(findthis);

    $( ".list_item:not(:contains("+ findthis +"))").hide();
    console.log(".list_item.data('stringtofind')");

});
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mk7yr62k/2/

Comment: _Is it possible to apply `:not(:contains())` selector to data-attribute?_ Simple answer is _You can't_

Comment: You need to use an attribute selector (`.list-item[data-stringtofind]')` rather than trying to use the `data()` method. But, that said, I'm still struggling to try and interpret the intent of your selector.

Comment: You could use the attribute contains selector, but be aware it would match on spaces too, ie. `bc de` would hit your first element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:contains` isn't related to attributes at all. You want an attribute substring selector:

```
$( ".list_item:not([data-stringtofind*='" + findthis + "'])").hide();
```

`[data-stringtofind*='xxx']` means "`xxx` anywhere in the `data-stringtofind` attribute." And of course, `:not` negates it.

Here's an example:

```js
var p = $("<p>").text("Waiting briefly...").appendTo(document.body);
setTimeout(function() {
  var findthis = "abc";
  $( ".list_item:not([data-stringtofind*='" + findthis + "'])").hide();
  p.text("Hid the ones not matching 'abc'");
}, 500);
```

```html
<div class="list_item" data-stringtofind="abc def">abc def</div>
<div class="list_item" data-stringtofind="ghi jkl">ghi jkl</div>
<div class="list_item" data-stringtofind="mno prs">mno prs</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well. Is there a way to make it case insensitive? I was using this code, but now it obviously can't work. `$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});`

Comment: @Val55: I've never played with adding pseudo-selectors. I think if you need case-insensitive matching, best to use a `filter` solution like Rory's instead.

Answer (score 2):

`:contains` is used to find an element by the text it contains, not the contents of an attribute, and hence is not suitable for what you require.

An alternative would be the attribute contains selector, but this will match on spaces too - ie. `bc de` would hit your first element.

To fix this you could use `filter()` and convert the data attribute of each element to an array and use `indexOf()` to find a match. Try this:

```
$('#find1').on('click', function () {
    var findthis = $('#keyword').val();

    $('.list_item').filter(function() {
        var arr = $(this).data('stringtofind').split(' ');
        return arr.indexOf(findthis) != -1;
    });
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/mk7yr62k/4/)

Comment: Thank you, your code also works very well. Since T.J. was the first one to answer, I have selected his answer.

Comment: One nit: Unless the OP needs the features of `data`, I wouldn't initialize the data cache unnecessarily, I'd just use `attr`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it searches for your string in each `.list_item` and hides it if there's no match.

```
$('#find1').on('click', function () {
    var findthis = $('#keyword').val();

    $(".list_item").each(function() {
        if ($(this).data('stringtofind').indexOf(findthis) == -1)
            $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: There's no need for this complexity, and there's no need to initialize jQuery's data cache for every element in the list (`data` is **not** just an accessor for `data-*` attributes).